# Array or sqlite query error

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite, arraylist

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code ?

It said error like this

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1636):     at com.example.KUHP_KUHAP_KUHperdata.PencPasalUndangKUHP.onTextChanged(PencPasalUndangKUHP.java:76)

E/AndroidRuntime(1636): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
```

This is my code where's it's error

main class

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
{
    String textform = s.toString();
    ArrayList<String> querybbrpa = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int position=0; position<listKamus.size(); position++)
    {
    String isidatabase = listKamus.get(position).toString();
    int posisiarray = position;
    KMP.main(textform, isidatabase, posisiarray);
    querybbrpa.set(position, KMP.value);
    }

    String query = TextUtils.join(" AND ", querybbrpa.toArray());
    listKamus = dbHelper.getAllPasalKUHPKnutmorris(query);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Data>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, listKamus);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Database class

```
public List<Data> getAllPasalKUHPKnutmorris(String query)
{
    List<Data> lisKamus = new ArrayList<Data>();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TB_KUHP, new String[] { COL_ID, COL_ID,
            COL_ISI, COL_PASAL }, query, null, null, null, COL_PASAL);
    if (cursor.getCount() >= 1)
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        do
        {
            Data data = new Data();
            data.setArti(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(COL_ISI)));
            data.setIstilah(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(COL_PASAL)));
            lisKamus.add(data);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return lisKamus;

}
```

KMP

```
public class KMP {

/** Failure array **/

private int[] failure;
public static String value;

/** Constructor **/

public KMP(String text, String pat, int pai)

{

    /** pre construct failure array for a pattern **/

    failure = new int[pat.length()];

    fail(pat);

    /** find match **/

    int pos = posMatch(text, pat);
    int pindex;
    pindex = pai + 1;
    if (pos == -1)

    KMP.value = "_id == ''";

    else

    KMP.value = "_id == '" + pindex + "'";

}

/** Failure function for a pattern **/

private void fail(String pat)

{

    int n = pat.length();

    failure[0] = -1;

    for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)

    {

        int i = failure[j - 1];

        while ((pat.charAt(j) != pat.charAt(i + 1)) && i >= 0)

            i = failure[i];

        if (pat.charAt(j) == pat.charAt(i + 1))

            failure[j] = i + 1;

        else

            failure[j] = -1;

    }

}

/** Function to find match for a pattern **/

private int posMatch(String text, String pat)

{

    int i = 0, j = 0;

    int lens = text.length();

    int lenp = pat.length();

    while (i < lens && j < lenp)

    {

        if (text.charAt(i) == pat.charAt(j))

        {

            i++;

            j++;

        }

        else if (j == 0)

            i++;

        else

            j = failure[j - 1] + 1;

    }

    return ((j == lenp) ? (i - lenp) : -1);

}

/** Main Function **/

public static void main(String textform, String isidatabase, int posisiarray)

{

    System.out.println("Knuth Morris Pratt Test\n");

    System.out.println("\nEnter Text\n");

    String text = textform;

    int pai = posisiarray; 

    System.out.println("\nEnter Pattern\n");

    String pattern = isidatabase;

    KMP kmp = new KMP(text, pattern, pai);        

}
}
```

Sorry if my explanation short. I'm still new in android. I want to search database data using knutmorris in ontextchange, so, when we type something in edittext/text change in edit text, the list below change using knutmorris.

Comment: indicate line 76 @ PencPasalUndangKUHP

Comment: It's `querybbrpa.set`.

Comment: line 76 is here "querybbrpa.set(position, KMP.value);"

Comment: change `querybbrpa.set(position, KMP.value);` to     `querybbrpa.add(KMP.value);` and try

Comment: Oh yeah, the error gone, thnx. But, it still not working. When i type something in edit text, it did not show any result, it's either show all or not show anything at all.

Comment: you don't use `textform` in onTextChanged, what you want to do?

Comment: I think    textform value is taken from my search box(edittext who work like search box). So, i send it's value to my knutmorris class.Then i put all data in database then change it to an array to be sent to that knut morris class too, to be compared one by one with that textform(edittext we type) with knutmorris algorithm. If the data found, the program show the data, if not, it won't, using this in database query "id == pindex", if not found "id == ''" then join all query from all array using "OR" so whenall array join, it will look like this "id == pindexarray1 OR id == pindexarray2" etc.